# Objective-C overriding a method with 2 arguments

Tags: objective-c, overriding

Class B.h

```
@interface ClassB : rndvzViewController {
    int sum, num1, num2;
}

-(void)sumPrint;
-(int)addNum1:(int)_num1 andNum2:(int)_num2;
```

Class B.m

```
-(int)addNum1:(int)_num1 andNum2:(int)_num2
{
    num1 = _num1;
    num2 = _num2;

    return sum = num1 + num2;
}

-(void)sumPrint
{
    NSLog(@"%d", sum);
}
```

class C.h

```
@interface ClassC : ClassB

@end
```

Class C.m

```
-(int)addNum1:(int)_num1 andNum2:(int)_num2
{

    //[self addNum1:num1 andNum2:num2];
    int interest = sum*.05;

    return interest;
}
```

Calling the methods :

```
ClassB* classB = [[ClassB alloc] init]; 
ClassC* classC = [[ClassC alloc] init];

[classB addNum1:12 andNum2:12];
classB.sumPrint;
//[classC addNum1:12 andNum2:12];
classC.sumPrint;
```

Output :
2014-09-09 14:07:48.919 ClassA[38418:60b] 24
2014-09-09 14:07:48.919 ClassA[38418:60b] 0

What am I doing wrong, why is classC.sumPrint returning 0, I want class C to print the sum from the values of class B * interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very basic OOP stuff. Not really Obj-C.

Anyway, if you want the `addNum1:andNum2:` method in C to first run the method in B then create it like this...

```
- (int)addNum1:(int)_num1 andNum2:(int)_num2
{
    return [super addNum1:_num1 andNum2:_num2] * 0.5;
}
```

It's a bit clunky though and the naming convention is off and I wouldn't store the data that way and many other things. But this will do what you want.

Comment: @suisied don't apologise :) just pointing out a few things to look at.